# Basic Availability Groups: can each AG share a listener?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

What are the potential consequences of using the same listener for each Availability Group when using Basic AGs? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can't share a listener between different AGs. Each one need to have its own.

A single listener is connected to its own BAG (Basic AG) and follows the primary node during failover.
It is possible to connect and access other databases in the same instance when connecting to a listener, but there is no certainty that the other databases are primary replica on the same node.

Sometime when you have multiples Ags you can find primary databases in different nodes. For example when someone did a manual failover or when a network error affects only some Ags or when a single ag reached the maximum failures in a specific period (a cluster option, usually 2 failures in6 hours).

In conclusion Ag are an high availability solution for database groups, but in the BAG the group consist in only one DB. If you need a group of database in the same node use enterprise edition of sql server or evaluate a Failover cluster instance.

Comment: Assuming this scenario: each DB has it's own basic AG, and that all the AGs share the same primary replica. If I use the same listener for all the AGs, and the primary replica goes down, ALL the AGs will failover to the secondary, correct?

Comment: Yes but this cover only a node failure case. You should consider a more frequent case that is a single BAG failover. IMO you have to forget about BAG and you should go for full feature enterprise AG. After all if you are looking for a High availability solution; indeed I can say that your sql in important so you can spend money for SQL Enterprise.

Comment: I looked into it a bit more. Apparently the same listener can't be used for all the BAGs. Each BAG needs it's own listener. In regards to a single BAG failover, I don't see how that can happen since all our BAGs will be on the same disk. Furthermore, there will be a job that fails over all the BAGs if one is already failed over. Are there other failure cases besides node/storage that I should be aware of?